# Custom Errors tag not working[Server Error in '/' Application.]

Tags: asp.net, exception, web-config

*I don't want to remove the error, I just want to hide this error (Server Error in '/' Application). but in web.config my (customErrors mode="Off") is not working .*

```
  <configuration>
        <system.web>
            <customErrors mode="Off"/>
        </system.web>
    </configuration>
```

***This is the error when i applied customErrors mode= "Off"***

> HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error The requested page cannot be
>   accessed because the related configuration data for the page is
>   invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing the rest of your configuration file it's not possible to know what is wrong with it but apart from that I think you are misunderstanding what `<customErrors mode="Off"/>` does. It will actually show the most detailed "yellow screen of death" of all the custom error modes. [From here:](https://stackify.com/web-config-customerrors-asp-net/)

> CustomErrors supports the following modes:
>
> - On – If defaultRedirect is specified, they will see that content.    Otherwise the default error screen with fewer details.
> - Off – Detailed    error details will be shown to the user. (the “yellow screen of death    screen”)
> - RemoteOnly – Default value. Detailed errors only are shown    to local users. Remote users receive custom error screens or fewer
>     details.

Comment: Thank you but i have already solved with another method by using Page_Load .                       
                                                                                                                        
  protected void Page_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
            Response.Redirect("~/ExceptionError.aspx");

        }